# How can MyEclipse compile Java classes without having a javac?

Tags: eclipse, javac, myeclipse

On my system, I have installed a Sun JRE (not JDK) and MyEclipse IDE.

I have searched for javac.exe in the installed files of MyEclipse in Program Files (windows platform), but there I got `no results found for javac.exe`.

Which tool is MyEclipse using to compile .java files?

Comment: Have you checked the folder C:\Program Files\Java\ ? Usually that will contain the JRE/JDK you have installed.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse includes its very own Java compiler, written by the project from scratch. It doesn't always quite agree with Oracle's compiler in some edge cases. They did this to get speedy incremental compilation. You can even use it from ant in place of the javac if you want to roll that way.

Answer (score -1):

#1: normally you need JDK. JDK mean Java **Development** Kit which includes the java-compiler `javac`

#2: Don't get what you really want to ask with the second question?

Comment: ##1 But .java files are also getting compiled with plain jre also (that's the bit i am not getting).

 ##2 check out the last comment of the link in 2nd question.

Comment: #1: hmmm... don't know how that should work. Java files are only _executed_ with JRE. (Java **Runtime** Environment) Want to know how that could be done if it was possible!

#2: Ah now I got it. I think anyone is notified who already posted somehow in this post. If not, there's no way to notify the others except posting another comment to the answer, respectively.